# How to change boostrap seach button class from btn-default to btn-primary?

Tags: theming, search

I'd like to change the class from btn-default to btn-primary like says in here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

```
<!-- Standard button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>

<!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy /sites/all/themes/bootstrap/theme/bootstrap/bootstrap-search-form-wrapper.func.php

to

/sites/all/themes/my-bootstrap-subtheme/templates

and edit that file at line 14:

```
 $output .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">';
```

to:

```
 $output .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">';
```

This might be helpful:
https://drupal.org/node/225125

Comment: I did this but it didn't work in my case. I have currently a solution which is copying the css style and applying it to `#form-id .btn` and it works. But it is less bootstrap spirit.

Comment: Ok. meant to suggest this too. https://drupal.org/node/171194 .